# Dependency Injection Serilog in .Net Framework

Tags: dependency-injection, serilog, .net-4.8

I am starting a .Net Framework desktop application and I'm trying to use Dependency Injection.  I have a working example where I Inject my SettingsService into the main window.  I am trying to get logging injected into my SettingsService but when I do it throws some errors.  I've tried setting the Logger after the host creates the service and everything works great. But that's not the DI way.

[image]

Below is the code:

Uses:

```
using ReceiptApplication.Services;
using Serilog;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Main:

```
public App()
{
    //SetupLogger();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt",
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
    .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("Hello, Serilog!");

    Log.CloseAndFlush();

    _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            ConfigureServices(services);
        })
        .Build();
}

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
    services.AddSingleton<newMainWindow>();
}

protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    await _host.StartAsync();
    // This is the line that throws the error.  
    // System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger'
    // while attempting to activate 'App.Services.SettingsService.
    var newMainWindow = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<newMainWindow>(); 
    newMainWindow.Show();
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Below is the SettingsService

```
class SettingsService : ISettingsService
{
    public static ILogger Log { get; set; }

    public SettingsService(ILogger log)
    {
        Log = log;
    }

    public void SetLog(ILogger log)
    {
        Log = log;
        Log.Debug("Log was set");
    }

    public void TestLog()
    {
        Log.Debug("This is a test");
    }

    public Settings GetSettings()
    {
        return new Settings();
    }

}
```

Here is the SettingService Interface

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
    Settings GetSettings();
    void SetLog(ILogger log);
    void TestLog();
}
```

Comment: naming conflict between Serilog ILogger and the built in ILogger from the framework..

Comment: The Serilog ILogger is not explicitly added to the container so it wont know how to resolve that type

Comment: Try using `ILogger<SettingsService>` instead in the `SettingsService ` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should take `ILogger` from the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` providing the name of your service as generic type parameter, i.e. `ILogger<SettingsService>`.

So the property and the constructor of your service should be as follows:

```
    public static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger Log { get; set; }

    public SettingsService(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<SettingsService> log)
    {
        Log = log;
    }
```